# What is numpy.c_ counterpart for NumSharp?

Tags: c#, numpy, numsharp

I am translating tensorflow program of ***python*** to ***C#***. And I didn't know how to deal with the method.
I search, but it seemed poor document for **NumSharp** document enable(if it is my ignore, please point me out to spot).
Could you help me to find out the same method exist in **Numsharp** or other method(s) with same effect? 
Thanks before~

Comment: `np.c_` is a version of `concatenate`.It uses some unique python tricks, so I wouldn't expect a clone to reproduce it.  But exactly what it's doing depends on the shape of its arguments.

Comment: There's a lot going on in `tensorflow` that `numpy` cline won't handle.  I don't know anything about `numsharp`, beyond what the name suggests, but you should try something  simpler before investing too effort.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is all that I can do. . .

Answer (score 0):

The **Numpy** which version you choose to use in C# project is important. 
If you use [Numpy](https://github.com/SciSharp/Numpy.NET), you could get a *np.c_* counterpart as *np.column_stack*. This may solve your problem. 
From [the help of contributor in Numpy](https://github.com/SciSharp/Numpy.NET/issues/85#issuecomment-979022771).